# How to save pictures with lower resolution in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf, matplotlib, rasterize

I need to save figures with many data (10.000 points per figure or more...) in lower resolution, to open them with the pdf viewer more quickly. I've heard that a proper combination of `rasterized = True` and `dpi` should be used in `pylab.savefig`.

What are these arguments? others may be used within savefig for this purpose?
Please give a clear example

PD: I have PYTHON 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After ploting or when you get the axis available:

```
pylab.gca().set_rasterized(True)
```

or for every axis `ax` you know

```
ax.set_rasterized(True)
```

Finally

```
pylab.savefig(file_name, dpi=your_choice)
```

where `dpi` could be 80, 160, 300, 600, etc.